# show range in message box VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have a function that selects a range based on a whole bunch of criteria from Sheet2. I'm trying to copy this range and to show/paste on Sheet1 or have it show in a message box.

```
Public Function findrulepos(target As Range, destination As Range) As String


Dim ruleStart As Range
Dim ruleEnd, ruleEnd2 As String
Dim Xcell, PasteRangeIndexCell As Range
Dim RuleRange As Range

Dim LastCell As Range
Dim FirstCell, IndexCell As Range
Dim WholeRule As Range


MaxRule = 100000
MaxRow = 100000


Sheets("ResRules").Select
For i = 2 To MaxRow

    If CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ResRules").Range("A" & i).Value) = CStr(target.Value) Then
       Set ruleStart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ResRules").Range("B" & i) '.offset(0, 1)
       Exit For

    End If

Next i

    'MsgBox (ruleStart.address)

 Set FirstCell = ruleStart.offset(1, -1)

 Set IndexCell = FirstCell

     Do Until IndexCell.Value <> "" Or IndexCell.Row >= MaxRow
          Set IndexCell = IndexCell.offset(1, 0)
       Loop

        If IndexCell.Value <> "" Then
        Set LastCell = IndexCell.offset(-1, 1)
    MsgBox (LastCell.Value)
    Else
        Set LastCell = Nothing
    End If

    Set WholeRule = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ResRules").Range("" & ruleStart.address & ":" & LastCell.address & "")


    End Function
```

This is the whole code to give me the range I require

I have added a watch and can see I am getting the correct range i.e. $B$3:$B$6 but cant copy this range to Sheet 1

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that you're trying to use to copy the range? You should be able to use `WholeRule.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`.

Comment: When you say function, do you mean a `User Defined Function` i.e it is being called from a sheet or a normal VBA function?

Comment: @ARich whole code added

Comment: @SiddharthRout user defined function - whole code there now.

Comment: If it is a UDF then see @Gary'sStudent reply

Answer (score 1):

If your function is being called from a worksheet cell, then **copy/paste** won't work since that type of function can only return a value to the cell in which it resides.  You need a function called from a **Sub**.

Comment: how do I do that ? WholeRule gives me the range in need to copy and paste.

Comment: + 1 True. UDF cannot change another cell.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Ok Thanks. So how can I get the contents of the WholeRule range to show (copy/paste) on the front page ? any ideas.

Comment: @grahamie: Gary has already mentioned what to do :) See his last sentence.

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes I saw that. I also asked him how to do it. im not sure of how to call the range (WholeRule) in a sub ...

Comment: @grahamie: Since Gary answered first, I would recommend waiting for his reply. If he doesn't post a reply in the next 24 hours then I will :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to get the address:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").value = WholeRule.address
```

or, if you want to copy the actual content in the cells:

```
WholeRule.copy Sheet1.Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys

worked it out

changed it to a Sub then

---

Public Sub ReturnRuleButton()
Call findrulepos(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Cells(2, 5), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Cells(2, 6))
End Sub

---